# Please explain this effect, Unity Textures

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, procedural-generation

The following code was taken from [here](http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/noise/). How Does this Particular Line Work -
`texture.SetPixel(x, y, new Color((x + 0.5f) * stepSize % 0.1f, (y + 0.5f) * stepSize % 0.1f, 0f) * 10f);` Multiplying Color with 10 and modulus with 0.1f is confusing me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All he's done in that line is have the color pattern repeat itself ten times over.

By calculating the modulo with 0.1, each loop of 0 - 1 will yield ten values (0, 0.1, 0.2...)

Further, by multiplying by 10, the color stays visible, and the result is the 10 x 10 grid pattern

Just take a look at the images the author has put up